# Kant's Prolegomena §13 - triangle example argument

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics, kant

In Prolegomena to Any Future Metaphysics, Kant argues that space (and time) are not qualities of objects, but a priori intuitions that allow the concepts of objects in our minds.

To argue in favor of this idea, he writes that

> those who cannot yet get free of the conception, as if space and time were actual qualities attaching to things in themselves, can exercise their acuity on the following paradox

This paradox is exemplified with

> two spherical triangles from each of the hemispheres, which have an arc of the equator for a common base, can be fully equal with respect to their sides as well as their angles, so that nothing will be found in either, when it is fully described by itself, that is not also in the description of the other

What I don't understand is, why the "hemisphere", or alternatively the coordinates of the point that does not touch the equator, is not considered as one of the *qualities* of the object, just as the common base and their sides were. How would Kant explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A coordinate is not an **intrinsic** property of a given point of the spheric triangle. It is a means that we use to locate points on the sphere.

The **intrinsic** properties of a spheric triangle are the angles between the sides and the sides themselves, also expressed as angles. Both spheric triangles of Kant's example have the same angles and sides, hence the same intrinsic properties.

Comment: What is an intrinsic property? Why is a side intrinsic but not a coordinate? What is the original German term for intrinsic?

Comment: A property of a geometric object is 'intrinsic' if it depends only on the object but not on the way the object is embedded into an ambient space. Intrinsic = intrinsisch (German). I do not know if Kant already has this technical term.

Comment: Document search didn't return "intrinsisch" to me in either the original Prolegomena or in Caygill's Kant Dictionary, so I assume Kant does not use that term. Could "innere" be interpreted the same way? About the argument it seems that: 1. Space is not a quality of objects because we disconsider an object's coordinates to ascribe "sameness". 2. We disconsider a coordinate because it is not an intrinsic property to it. 3. To be instrinsic means it does not refer to position in space. Looks circular to me. Not that I find circular arguments fallacious, but is there anything else to it?

Comment: Yes: 'innere'='intrinsisch'. ad 3) and 2): I agree. Then the coordinate of a point of the triangle is not intrinsic because it is just a means to locate the point in space. ad 1) I agree too. Two triangles in the plane are congruent if and only if they agree with respect to sides and angles. Kant carries over this criterion to spheric triangles. Why do you consider the chain 1)2)3) circular?

Comment: I guess to be really circular we would need something like "If space is not a quality of objects, then its 'properies' cannot be intrinsic". But maybe there's no reason to assert that? If not, then 3) is left as an axiomatic proposition, but I can't see that as obvious

Comment: Is there any reason he used the example of triangles on the curved surface of a sphere, rather than the more well-known idea of triangles in a plane described by Euclidean geometry? It seems like either would work either way if he was just saying two triangles can have different locations but the same intrinsic geometry.

Comment: Mathematics takes as definition: intrinsic geometric property  = not dependent on embedding the object into an ambient space. Example: Gauss curvature of a surface is an intrinsic property of the metric, other curvature values may depend on the choice of a coordinate system to calculate the metric. Coordinate systems are not intrinsic properties of the object.